# How to declare transpose range as cells in another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to split a string in cell by "|" and further split the string(0) by " ". My question is for the last line of code. I want to define range using cell position but it causes error. Why is that so?

```
 what = Split(Cells(r, 3).Value, "|")
 titletxt = what(0)

 x = Split(titletxt, " ")

 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B5").Value = Application.Transpose(x)
```

From this

```
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B5").Value = Application.Transpose(x)
```

I want to change to following--> but there is error.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(5, 2)) = Application.Transpose(x)
```

Comment: `Cells` by itself will always refer the the ActiveSheet, so if Sheet2 is not active your code will fail.  Try instead `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Resize(3, 1)`

Comment: I tried but it is out of range now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't fit to comment but try this:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(5, 2)) = Application.Transpose(x)
End With
```

Does above work?